# PDF fonts get embedded but hyperlinks inside document do not work

Tags: fonts, pdftex, overleaf, linux, embedding

I have a .pdf file, in which I have to embed all the fonts.
I found out that I should use this command:
`gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dPrinted=false -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=edited_file.pdf myfile.pdf`
but the pdf file loses its interactiveness. For example, I have hyperlinks that jump to references, or clickable table of contents that becomes not clickable anymore after executing this command.
Can you please help me to find a solution.... I have only linux, so everything Windows-related is not an option.

Comment: why don't you embed the fonts in myfile.pdf directly?

Comment: how? I do not have Adobe Acrobat or pdf24 editors..

Comment: Isn't myfile.pdf created with pdflatex?

Comment: I'm using Overleaf. So I just directly download it from there

Comment: well then find out why you are missing fonts (that is not the default, nowadays pdflatex always embeds all fonts).

Comment: it's mainly because of plots that I have put as .png or .pdf ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147340/discussion-between-somerandomguest-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: png has not fonts, that is a bitmap. And if you have plots with missing fonts then preprocess them with ghostscript.

Comment: I continued in "chat"